# NullPointerException in appcompat-v22 for Eclair devices

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Has anyone tested their app against Android 2.1 after updating to appcompat-v22? My app works fine with appcompat-v21, and Android 2.2. I've got a navigation drawer activity with a Toolbar, and my fragment list as my activity content. I'm using build tools 22.0.1, targetSdkVersion 22 and appcompat-v7:22.0.0

My crash seems to indicate that a checkbox in my fragmentlist could be the culprit, here was the original stack:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.mutate(StateListDrawable.java:241)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:140)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintCheckBox.<init>(TintCheckBox.java:49)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintCheckBox.<init>(TintCheckBox.java:41)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.createView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:790)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:548)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at com.myapp.myapp.adapter.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:79)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2818)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1751)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1283)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1582)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2478)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6892)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1021)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone seen something similar when updating their app to v22? Is anyone even supporting Android 2.1 anymore?

Comment: Nobody is supporting 2.1 anymore.  Even 2.2 is  .4% of installs  according to Google Play.  People either target 2.3 (about 7%) or 4.0 (about 6%, but easier to support).  3.0 is so low it isn't charted.  It just doesn't make financial sense for a company or effort sense for a hobbyist to do more.  You can see the stats at https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: I can't tell if OP is trolling about Eclair.

Comment: I wasn't trolling, I understand that the numbers are low.. My app is at around 0.2%, but i am just surprised that "appcompat-v7" which is supposed to support back to android 2.1 would break like this. I take it from the responses here that I should just let go :)

Comment: `appcompat-v7` (you are using version 22.0.0) is intended to support Eclair MR1 (API 7, 2.1.x) so please file a bug on the [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list). It is probably a framework bug triggered by the compat tinting implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alan - I've created a new issue for this. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in support library 22.1.0 (see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161539)